# Intellij idea-IU-171.3780.107 ugly after upgrade from idea-IU-162.2228.15 in Ubuntu

Tags: intellij-idea, ubuntu-16.04

I have just upgraded my Intellij IDEA (Java IDE) from idea-IU-162.2228.15 to idea-IU-171.3780.107 (folder names of the downloads) as suggested by the update manager. Now I am wondering, that the UI is ugly in my opinion. I like the UI of the idea-IU-162.2228.15 much more.

- The UI from idea-IU-162.2228.15: [image: The UI from idea-IU-162.2228.15]
- The "ugly" (my opinion ;) UI from idea-IU-171.3780.107: [image: The "ugly" (my opinion ;) UI from idea-IU-171.3780.107]

Is this a new UI or a error in my system? I am using Ubuntu 16.04. If it is an error, how can I fix it and if not, how can I get the old UI back?

Edit:

Ok, tank to Rumid. I have fixed the icons problem. But the fonts aren't as in the old IDE:

- Fonts in the 2016 Version:

[image: Fonts in the 2016 Version]

- Fonts in the 2017 Version:

[image: Fonts in the 2017 Version]

I honestly don't know if I haved this in the old (2016) by myself. I checked the settings in both IDEs but I could not see any difference in the settings. How can I get the fonts of my 2016 Idea?

Comment: I don't see a major difference.  They are both ugly.  What aspect has changed for the worse, in your opinion?

Comment: Do you mean the icons, the fonts or both?

Comment: Font has changed in Arch also. And everything became  awkward (not ugly). Several months ago the same happened with another update. If you dislike changes, why do you upgrade?

Comment: You seem to have mixed up your screenshots. The first one is of IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 the second one is of IntelliJ IDEA 2016..2.5.

Comment: I mean the project explorer and the font of the menus - the editor is good. I wanted to upgrade for the new features of IntelliJ. It sounds, that this is no error from my system and the new version just looks like this, isn't it?

Comment: @ThomasDeniffel fonts for me looks normal now, I think it was fixed in recent upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a bug, the new icons were provided in Idea 2016.3.

If you don't like it you can install this plugin: [Idea 2016.2 Icon Pack](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7285-idea-2016-2-icon-pack).

Comment: Thats it. Thank you! For other lazy readers: Strg+Alt+A > Type "Plugins" > Search for "Idea 2016.2 Icon Pack" > Search in repositories > Install > Restart.